# PowerShell: Comparing 2 variables

Tags: variables, powershell, comparison

Can anyone tell me why the code below is not working? I want to end up with the drives that match both e.g. F: and G:

I know its something simple but cant figure it out.  A quick explanation would be welcome.  Thanks

```
$USBDrives =$null 
$WMIUSBDrives="E:","F:","G:"
$SystemDrives="D:","F:","G:"
$USBDrives = $SystemDrives | Where {$_ -contains $WMIUSBDrives}
$USBDrives
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually should use this other way around... :)

```
$USBDrives = $SystemDrives | Where {$WMIUSBDrives -contains $_}
$USBDrives
```

The operator that works the way you want is -in that was added in v3.
HTH
Bartek

Answer (score 0):

For the above to work, I think $WMIUSBDrives and $SystemDrives would have to match.

Try this instead:

```
$USBDrives =$null 
$WMIUSBDrives="E:","F:","G:"
$SystemDrives="D:","F:","G:"
foreach($drive in $WMIUSBDrives)
{
    if($SystemDrives  -contains $drive){$USBDrives += $drive}
}
$USBDrives
```

Comment: ive updated the question with more information following your answer.   I want to end up with the drives that match both.   $USBDrives should contain "F:","G:"